# Convert several columns from integer to numeric in R data.frame

Tags: r, type-conversion, lapply

I would like to convert columns from 2 to 13 (the last one) from integer to numeric.

For one column, I use the following code:

```
dades$V3 <- as.numeric(dades$V3)
```

I want to convert columns from 2 to 13 with the same command. I create this vector:

```
dades<-2:13
```

Then, how do I use `lapply`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

We can use `lapply` on the subset of dataset (`dades[2:13]`), convert to `numeric` and assign it back to those columns.

```
dades[2:13] <- lapply(dades[2:13], as.numeric)
```

Comment: You are missing a comma, the code should read: ´dades[,2:13]´ otherwise you will introduce NAs by coercion on column 1 row 2:13.

Comment: @krenz Not really.  By default `data.frame` with no comma in indexing, it is taken as column index.  (But you are right that it is row,column index. ) You may be using a different data structure ie. data.table etc.

Comment: You are indeed correct.